# Cual seria el equivalente a este en srvsql_connect?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, mssql, sqlsrv

quisiera saber cual es el equivalente a:

```
$conn = mssql_conect("ipdestino","usuario","pass") or 
die ('error conexion SQL');
```

Veran con la de arriba abro el puerto de un server dedicado 1433 y conecta desde cualquier hosting pero el siguiente parece servir solo localmente:

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

pues no se identifica si lo pongo en un hosting fuera del dedicado la ip donde conectara agradezco respuesta gracias.

Segun un comentario agregue y edite asi:

```
<?php
$serverName = "209.145.60.200\sqlexpress, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PS_Gamedata", "UID"=>"JoseZitrusasda94x", "PWD"=>"asdasdfff231");
$conn = @sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 ?>
```

Me dio este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /home/createso/public_html/shaiyaxtreme/includes/srv.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/createso/public_html/shaiyaxtreme/includes/srv.php on line 4
```

Sera que debo usar alguna version de PHP especifica actualmente uso php 7.0

Comment: ¿Hay algún error? ¿Tienes los controladores apropiados en el entorno donde quieres usar `sqlsrv_connect()`?

Comment: amigo como dije la pregunta es mas que CLARA quiero saber el equivalente si notas en una la conexion es REMOTA la del MSSQL y en la otra es LOCAL SOLAMENTE. por favor lea bien y con atencion. ya que necesito que la conexion srvsql sea remota NO LOCAL. ahora que no se como o donde colocar la IP.

Comment: La IP iría donde tienes `serverName`. Así, dada la IP `1.2.3.4`, tu variable debería quedar de este modo: `$serverName = "1.2.3.4\sqlexpress, 1433";` Si el código no funciona, por favor, captura el error de conexión y agrégalo a la pregunta. En el **Ejemplo 1** del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) podrás ver cómo se capturan los errores de conexión.

Comment: listo edite la pregunta

Comment: Ese error significa que no tienes instalado o no tienes activado el [controlador de SQL Server para PHP](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). El mismo puede estar instalado, pero no activado, por lo que deberías revisar tu archivo `php.ini`